# How to create a symbolic link in a linux directory?

Tags: symbolic-link

I want to create a symlink that should point to another directory.

Like inside directory `/var/www/vhosts/ecash-staging.com/` should be a symlink named as `ecash_root`   that should pointing to --> `/var/www/vhosts/ecash_cfe`.

How is this possible ?

I have googled but there some people said that there should be a dir ecash_root exist in `/var/www/vhosts/ecash_cfe/...`  but I do not want that.

i just have to create symlink in `/var/..../ecash-staging.com/` name as `ecash_root` that should point to `/var/www/vhosts/ecash_cfe` but should not be a ecash_root dir inside `/var/www/vhosts/ecash_cfe`.

thanks to all

Comment: open a terminal, enter `ln --help` or/and `man ln` and read it for additional information...

Comment: You needed to be in Target folder
ln -s <source-file> name

Answer (score 193, accepted):

Use `ln`:

```
ln -s /var/www/vhosts/ecash_cfe /var/www/vhosts/ecash-staging.com/ecash_root
```

- `-s` stands for symbolic link
- `/var/www/vhosts/ecash_cfe` is the source file
- `/var/www/vhosts/ecash-staging.com/ecash_root` is the link name

Comment: 2 commands  worked for me . one of them that is @heemayl mentioned above . and other one in current directory just ran the command ls -s /var/www/vhosts/ecash_cfe   ecash_root .  same worked both . good .

Comment: @heemayl isn't it the other way around?

Comment: nope, target goes first, see [docs](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ln), also @WaqasRana's comment mentions the wrong command "ls"

Comment: For me, this creates a file...

Comment: ln -s target_directory short_cut_file_path_and_name
Example : ln -s /media/  ./media_shortcut

Explanation : Creating shortcut file in the same directory with name media_shortcut which references to /media/ directory

Comment: @YanickRochon et al — make sure you are in the target directory, not the source directory when you create the symlink.

Comment: @YanickRochon et al - I would say you should make sure to give the absolute path to the directory the link should be pointing to

Comment: You should also use the `-T` option, so that the created file is always `/var/www/vhosts/ecash-staging.com/ecash_root`. Without that, `ln` may try to create a link inside there.